# NFS hangs on resume from suspend [after Wily update]

Tags: suspend, nfs, 15.10

I updated to Wily a week ago. Previously, nfs (by autofs) mounts worked fine after suspend. Now they don't, and it's causing all apps that have open files on the network to hang and complain.

When I try to reboot / shut down, it hangs on closing the NFS mounts.

I didn't change anything with the autofs or nfs configs, except to try soft mounting after this happened (no help).

This is on a Lenovo X1 Carbon 3rd gen. Everything else appears to be fine with this update, but not that.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot / fix?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue (hanging after resume).  Though the OP didn't say, I assume he is mounting /home over NFS.

The hang seems to be specific to NFSv4.  Using NFSv3 works.  In this case you also need "nolock" (otherwise it will hang when trying to log into a GUI session).

So your fstab entry should look like this:

```
server:/home /home   nfs     vers=3,nolock   0   0
```